# Custom drawable with Layer-list

Tags: android, layer-list

I'm going to create a drawable like below image that is included an arrow image.

[image]

When I use layer-list , arrow image appear in middle of my drawable!!!

Please let me know how can I achieve it ...

**UPDATE**:
This is my Layer-List:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#d5d5d5"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#242425"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_arrow"></item>
```

Comment: You'd better use 9 patch instead of `layer-list`. http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch

Comment: @Seinmon,I can't use 9patch images. Because my drawable has a border (1px or 1dp); when I scale its width, width border will be thinner than height border !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a drawable resource file set bitmap as the root element, then set the `android:gravity="left"` and use this bitmap file as drawable in your layer-list item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
       android:gravity="left"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

layer-list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item>
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">

                 <stroke  android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/blue" />
                <solid android:color="@color/silver" />

            </shape>
       </item>

       <item android:drawable="@drawable/stack" />

</layer-list>
```

Comment: You could also use our image directly as background => <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:gravity="left" /> You can set a width and height, add margin with left.right properties, use android:gravity="right|center_vertical" ... the preview will always be wrong but il will work.